# Automatically turn off VPN for select website/IP

Tags: networking, vpn, unix, routing, iptables

Using a VPN for privacy and security on a Unix machine. There are a few sites that I can only access through my whitelisted IP for work. Is there a way to automatically turn off my VPN (or route traffic using my static IP) when accessing certain websites?  Hoping to do this outside of application settings and in config files.

Answer (score 1):

Your ability to do this may be dependent on the specific VPN software you are using and how much control over its configuration you have. What you are looking for is calle "inverse split tunnelling" in the VPN world. Note that this will be controlled on a per IP/network basis, not based on DNS name for the site.

One tack you could try would be to add the destination IPs for the specific sites to your system routing table with the gateway (next-hop) address set to the IP address of your upstream Internet router. Whether this works will be dependent on how the VPN client you are using hooks into the network stack of the system to redirect traffic over the VPN.